# Appending value-pair to a dictionary-key

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I am reading a textfile with many sections. I would have a dictionary like:

```
stringArrayCompleteData['Objekt']['Mobile']    
stringArrayCompleteData['Objekt']['address']
stringArrayCompleteData['Header']['devicenumber']
stringArrayCompleteData['Header']['departmentemailaddresse']
and much more
```

But in my loob, always the new value would not be appended, the values would be overwritten. And then i have only the last value.

```
var stringArray = fullImportContent!.componentsSeparatedByString("\n")
var stringArrayCompleteData = Dictionary<String, Dictionary<String, Any>>()
var arrIndexSection : String = "NoHeader"

        for singleRow in stringArray
        {
            if(singleRow != "")
            {
                switch singleRow {
                    case "#Header":
                        arrIndexSection = singleRow.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString("#", withString: "", options: NSStringCompareOptions.LiteralSearch, range: nil)
                    case "#Objekt":
                        arrIndexSection = singleRow.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString("#", withString: "", options: NSStringCompareOptions.LiteralSearch, range: nil)
                    case "#Baustelle":
                        arrIndexSection = singleRow.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString("#", withString: "", options: NSStringCompareOptions.LiteralSearch, range: nil)
                    case "#Auftraggeber":
                        arrIndexSection = singleRow.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString("#", withString: "", options: NSStringCompareOptions.LiteralSearch, range: nil)
                    case "#Architekt":
                        arrIndexSection = singleRow.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString("#", withString: "", options: NSStringCompareOptions.LiteralSearch, range: nil)
                    case "#Vermittler":
                        arrIndexSection = singleRow.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString("#", withString: "", options: NSStringCompareOptions.LiteralSearch, range: nil)
                    case "#Regulierer":
                        arrIndexSection = singleRow.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString("#", withString: "", options: NSStringCompareOptions.LiteralSearch, range: nil)
                    case "#Versicherung":
                        arrIndexSection = singleRow.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString("#", withString: "", options: NSStringCompareOptions.LiteralSearch, range: nil)
                    case "#Kontaktstellen":
                        arrIndexSection = singleRow.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString("#", withString: "", options: NSStringCompareOptions.LiteralSearch, range: nil)
                    case "#Dateien":
                        arrIndexSection = singleRow.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString("#", withString: "", options: NSStringCompareOptions.LiteralSearch, range: nil)
                    default:
                        //Here the multiple array would be filled
                        var arrSingleRow = singleRow.componentsSeparatedByString(";")

                        if( arrSingleRow.count > 0  )
                        {
                            if( arrIndexSection == "Kontaktstellen" )
                            {
                                //TODO: Kontaktstellen einlesen

                                //#Kontaktstellen
                                //Baustelle;0;348873;;;;0
                                //Baustelle;0;381263;;Albrecht;0815;0
                                //Regulierer/SV;0;171979;Josef;Eder;08546/911055;0
                                println( "Kontaktstellendaten" )
                                println( singleRow )
                            }
                            else if( arrIndexSection == "Dateien" )
                            {
                                //TODO: Dateien einlesen

                                //#Dateien
                                //11022015090007_BEmail_INNNUE_21102014141534.pdf; 99; Email an eva.nuhn@mbs-service.de

                                println( "Dateiendaten" )
                                println( singleRow )
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                stringArrayCompleteData[arrIndexSection] = [arrSingleRow[0]: arrSingleRow[1]]
```

// Here i tried to update the value and append a value
//stringArrayCompleteData[arrIndexSection]?.updateValue(arrSingleRow[1], forKey: arrSingleRow[0])
                                    // Error: cannot mutate a constant dictionary

```
                            }
                        }
                }
            }
        }
        println( stringArrayCompleteData )
        for key in stringArrayCompleteData.keys {
            println("Key: \(key)")
        }
```

Here are the results of the println()

> [Auftraggeber: [Telefon2: ], Regulierer: [Telefon2: ], Baustelle: [Telefon2: ], Versicherung: [Telefon2: 01805], Header: [iPadNr:3E24-45B8-A2AC-7E3501BED78A], Objekt: [WeitererHinweis: Test]]
>
> Key: Auftraggeber
>
> Key: Regulierer
>
> Key: Baustelle
>
> Key: Versicherung
>
> Key: Header
>
> Key: Objekt

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't understand exactly what you are doing but ... why do you use a dictionary where the value is another dictionary? Wouldn't be better to use a dictionary of Array instead?

Something like

```
 Dictionary<String, Array<Any>>()
```

Or better

```
   [String:[Any]]()
```

In this way the key of the Dictionary is the "section name" and the values of the Array (that you can add using the .append method) are just the values.

Hope this help, if not try to clarify what input and what output do you expect from your code, I know you're not a native speaker but it's difficult to understand what you really need here.

Bye!
D.